# Command-line tool to show bandwidth percentage usage

Tags: linux, networking, bash, command-line-interface

In a Linux server, I need to see the network percentage utilization, like for example you can see into the windows task manager:

[image]

Do you know some linux **command line (NOT GUI)** tool which do this job?
I googled a lot, but i didn't find anything like what i need..

Comment: Any of these? [18 commands to monitor network bandwidth on Linux server](http://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-monitor-network/)

Answer (score 1):

iptraf or bwm-ng
If you are using RHEL/Centos are both in EPEL repository but the show speed in KB/s not in percentage.
Below an example of bwm-ng

```
bwm-ng v0.6.1 (probing every 0.500s), press 'h' for help
  input: /proc/net/dev type: rate
  /         iface                   Rx                   Tx                Total
  ==============================================================================
             eth0:           0.13 KB/s            0.41 KB/s            0.54 KB/s
               lo:           4.56 KB/s            4.56 KB/s            9.12 KB/s
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            total:           4.69 KB/s            4.97 KB/s            9.65 KB/s
```